# Force page redirect on token errors with a custom decorator using flask-jwt-extended

Tags: flask-jwt-extended

I am using the Flask JWT-Extended library to implement JWT access tokens. 
When a user's token expires, is invalid, or non existent, what happens by default is Flask returns a JSON like:

`{"msg": "Missing cookie \"access_token_cookie\""}`

I want to make a decorator that wraps the `@jwt_required` but does an internal redirect (like to a login page) instead of returning a JSON like above.

Here's an example decorator:

```
def redirect_if_error(view_function):
    @wraps(view_function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        jwt_data = _decode_jwt_from_request(request_type='access')

        # Do custom validation here.
        if 'identity' in jwt_data:
            authorized = True
        else:
            authorized = False

        if not authorized:
            return redirect('login', code=302)

        return view_function(*args, **kwargs)

    return jwt_required(wrapper)
```

and an example page protected page route, that I'd like Flask to redirect the user to if any sort of token error occurs:

```
@mod.route('/')
@redirect_if_error
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

My problem is I cannot figure out how to override the default JSON return with a redirect. If there is any error, the logic instead the wrap function is ignored, and some sort of error message is outputted.

**Is there a better way to override the default behavior using a new decorator?**

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to accomplish this with a custom decorator. Simply catching the exception with a try - except worked, like:

```
def redirect_if_jwt_invalid(view_function):
    @wraps(view_function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # attempt to grab the jwt from request
        try:
            jwt_data = _decode_jwt_from_request(request_type='access')
        except:
            jwt_data = None
        # if the grab worked and the identity key is in the dict then proceed
        if jwt_data and 'identity' in jwt_data:
            return view_function(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect('login', code=302)

    return wrapper
```

and the route:

```
from Utilities.Helpers import redirect_if_jwt_invalid

mod = Blueprint('page_routes', __name__)

@mod.route('/')
@redirect_if_jwt_invalid
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: You should use the exported `verify_jwt_in_request` function instead of dipping into the internal `_decode_jwt_from_request` function. The latter has no guarantees that it will work the same between versions, and short circuits some of the other features in the extension. See the official docs here: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_decorators.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the decorator I use

```
from functools import wraps
from flask_jwt_extended import verify_jwt_in_request
...
...


def redirect_if_jwt_invalid(view_function):
@wraps(view_function)
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    # attempt to grab the jwt from request
    try:
        verify_jwt_in_request()
        return view_function(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        return redirect(url_for('backoffice.login'), code=302)
   
return wrapper
```

and the route:

```
@app_file_backoffice.route("/route", methods=["GET"])
@redirect_if_jwt_invalid
def get_route():
   users = User.query.all()
   ...
```